# Postgresql timestamp difference greater than 1 hour

Tags: postgresql

Hi I have a entrytime and exittime timestamp in my database, how can I query it to display only ones where the person exited more than an hour later;

```
Select * from store where EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (exittime - entrytime))/3600 >60
```

That's what I have so far but it won't work, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please specify what "*won't work*" means.

Comment: You are looking for times more than 60 hours apart.  Of that doesn't work if you want times more than one hour apart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just subtract the values and compare it with an interval

```
Select * 
from store 
where exittime - entrytime > interval '1 hour';
```

This assumes that both columns are defined as `timestamptz` or `timestamp`